# Css order property for android browser and older safari

Tags: css, responsive-design, safari, flexbox

I am using the css order property:

```
#product_addtocart_form {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
    #product_addtocart_form .product-img-box {order: 1;}
    #product_addtocart_form .product-shop {order: 2;}
```

My problem is that on android browser and older safari version (iphone 4, 4s ) doesn't work . Is there a webkit css code for older safari and android browser ? Thx in advance

Comment: Do they support flexbox? If not then the answer is no.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=order

Comment: @Saba - Wrong link. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) outputs:

```
#product_addtocart_form .product-img-box {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}

#product_addtocart_form .product-shop {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
}
```

**Edit 2**

For the container, the prefixed styles are:

```
#product_addtocart_form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: You probably also need to prefix the other `flexbox` properties you are using too.

Comment: I updated my post, can you update yours accordingly ?

Comment: hehe, no worries. Glad to help :)